# What's the fastest ferry to get from Italy to Albania?

Tags: italy, ferries, albania

I'm looking for the fastest ferry that travels from anywhere in Italy to anywhere in Albania. The ferry should have a regular schedule and should be in service in September 2015.

Comment: Note that the fastest one will inevitably the shortest route.

Comment: That's something I'm not 100% sure about and one reason why I asked this question initially. Think about a slightly longer route that is traveled by a way faster ferry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ferries to Albania, be it to Durazzo or Vlorë, depart Italy from either Ancona, Bari or Brindisi (ordered by distance from longest to shortest):

[image]
<sup>*Mappa traghetti*, [Cemar](http://www.cemar.it/dest/traghetti_albania.htm), Fair Use</sup>

It is safe to assume that the duration of the journey will depend on the distance between the two cities. [Searching on Direct Ferries for a return journey in September 2015](http://ww2.directferries.it/ferry/secure/booking_redirect_df.aspx?stdc=DF10IT&grid=0&rfid=868&psgr=1&curr=2&retn=true&rfidr=869) yields the following result in terms of travel time (A: outward, R: return):

- **Ancona - Durazzo**: 20h00m A | 20h00m R
- **Bari - Durazzo**: 09h00m A | 20h00m R
- **Brindisi - Vlorë**: 07h30m A | 05h00m R

See below for a screenshot of the search results:

[image: Ferry search result]

Some routes are available only seasonally and not throughout the year. According to Cemar, [only Adria Ferries runs all year round, with 3 weekly departures](http://www.cemar.it/dest/traghetti_albania.htm):

> #### Adria Ferries: (Traghetti online Tel. 892.112)
>
> Servizio trisettimanale svolto con la nave traghetto "Riviera del Conero" e "Riviera Adriatica"
>
> - Da Ancona per Durazzo (Albania) 3 partenze settimanali tutto l'anno
> - Da Durazzo (Albania) ad Ancona 3 partenze settimanali tutto l'anno
> - Da Bari (Italia) a Durazzo (Albania) 3 partenze settimanali tutto l'anno
> - Da Durazzo (Albania) a Bari (Italia) 3 partenze settimanali tutto l'anno

Cemar also says that Venezia Lines runs a fast catamaran from Bari to Durazzo. However searching on the company website seems to indicate that the service was discontinued, as the only lines one can find depart from Venice and aim for Croatia.